# Displaying selected image on a modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a simple application using **Vue.js** where users can browse books by choosing author names. I then added a modal to display books however each time I click on different cards it keeps showing the same image. I tried to loop and used the following code:

```html
    <div class="modal" v-for="item in card">
        <img v-bind:src="item.img" class="book-enlarge" alt="book" />
    </div>
```

Here's my **HTML** code:

```html
    <div
        v-show="author === '' || author === item.author"
        :class="{ active: author === item.author }"
        v-for="(item, index) in card"
        v-bind:data-index="index + 1"
        @click="showModal(index)"
    >
        <img v-bind:src="item.img" alt="book" class="card__book" />
        <div class="card__body">
            <h1 class="card__title">{{ item.title }}</h1>
            <p class="card__author">
                <span class="card__author--mod">By:</span>
                {{ item.author }}
            </p>
            <p class="card__release">
                <span class="card__release--mod">Release Date:</span>
                {{ item.release }}
            </p>
        </div>

        <form v-bind:action="item.link" target="_blank">
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Buy on Amazon" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <div ref="close" @click="close" class="overlay__close">
            &#8855;
        </div>
        <div class="modal" v-for="item in card">
            <img v-bind:src="item.img" class="book-enlarge" alt="book" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my **Vue.js** code:

```js
const cardDescriptions = [
  {
    img: `../books-img/book-1.jpg`,
    title: `A Life on Our Planet: My Witness Statement and a Vision for the Future`,
    author: `David Attenborough`,
    release: `2020-10-01`,
    link: `https://www.amazon.co.uk/Life-Our-Planet-Witness-Statement/dp/1529108276/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=a+life+on+our+planet&qid=1610306225&quartzVehicle=45-608&replacementKeywords=a+on+our+planet&sr=8-1`,
  },
  {
    img: `../books-img/book-2.jpg`,
    title: `Life on Air`,
    author: `David Attenborough`,
    release: `2010-05-20`,
    link: `https://www.amazon.co.uk/Life-Air-David-Attenborough/dp/1849900019/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=life+on+air&qid=1610306334&quartzVehicle=45-608&replacementKeywords=on+air&sr=8-1`,
  },
  {
    img: `../books-img/book-3.jpg`,
    title: `HTML, CSS and JavaScript in easy steps`,
    author: `Mike McGrath`,
    release: `2020-08-06`,
    link: `https://www.amazon.co.uk/HTML-CSS-JavaScript-easy-steps/dp/184078878X/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=HTML%2C+CSS+and+JavaScript+in+easy+steps%3A+%28In+Easy+Steps%29&qid=1610306384&sr=8-1`,
  },
  {
    img: `../books-img/book-4.jpg`,
    title: `HTML5 in easy steps, 2nd edition`,
    author: `Mike McGrath`,
    release: `2017-02-17`,
    link: `https://www.amazon.co.uk/HTML5-easy-steps-Mike-McGrath/dp/1840787546/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=HTML5+in+easy+steps%3A+%282nd+edition%29&qid=1610306431&sr=8-1`,
  },
];

new Vue({
  el: '#container',
  data: {
    card: cardDescriptions,
    author: '',
  },
  methods: {
    displayBooks: function (e) {
      this.author = e.target.value;
    },
    showModal: function (index) {
      document.querySelector('#overlay').style.display = 'block';
      console.log(index + 1);
    },
  },
  computed: {
    filteredNames: function () {
      const authors = [];
      this.card.forEach(item => {
        if (!authors.includes(item.author)) {
          authors.push(item.author);
        }
      });
      return authors;
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#overlay',
  data: {
    card: cardDescriptions,
  },
  methods: {
    close: function () {
      const closeModal = this.$refs.close.parentNode;
      closeModal.style.display = 'none';
    },
  },
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank You!

Comment: You are running two apps instead of using components.  You should have only one call to `new Vue` and everything should be inside one div where the app is mounted.

Comment: Hey @Dan, 

Thank you for your response. I tried implementing your solution but it still displays the same image.

Comment: Hi Rabin, I didn't give a solution. It would be best to edit your question to show what you tried in response to my comment

Comment: I removed second **Vue instance** and moved modal inside a `<div>` container where the app is mounted. I then used a `for loops` to loop through images.

Answer (score 0):

You're example still shows two instances of Vue.

You need to use the `require` like so:

```html
    <img v-bind:src="require`@/assets/${item.img}`" alt="book" class="card__book" />
```

`@` is the root of your `src` folder and you need to give some static string to your require for it to work.

Moreover you need to provide your v-for a `key` so vue can identify unique elements

```html
    <div class="modal" v-for="(item, index) in card" :key="index">
        <img v-bind:src="item.img" class="book-enlarge" alt="book" />
    </div>
```